# Alternative to vlookup with exact and approximate match doesnt work

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup, string-matching, vba

```
Cell A1: 0553400710 
Cell A2: John
Cell B1: ['0553400710', '0553439406']
```

Note:

1. List item Cell B1 has a fixed format of `['number','number,'number',...... ]`
2. A1 and A2 are user input values

I want to match 0553400710 in Cell A1 with ['0553400710', '0553439406'] in Cell B1.

If it matches, I want to return A2: John.

Is it possible?

Vlookup failed to work by the way. I am looking for some technique which uses the advantage of fixed format

Picture 1: This is the formula i have tried

[image: Formula]

Picture 2: This is the table where the vlookup is showing wrong values

[image]

Picture 3: This is the array where vlookup check

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SO!  Would you please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/38149171/edit) to include what formulas you already tried, and what results you had?  A screenshot of your spreadsheet would also be helpful in visualizing the problem.  Thank you!

Comment: @Joanne you can use `Instr` function to check if the sub-string in Cell A1 is found at Cell B1.

Comment: I have updated the pictures

Answer (score 2):

Going by the sample data (and references) in your narrative and ignoring the image(s), a simple wildcard match should be sufficient.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(A:A, MATCH("*"&A1&"*",B:B, 0)+1), "")
```

[image: wildcard_match]

Comment: is it possible to make number in A1 and John in A2?

Comment: and the array list in A3?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried index/match?

=index(return_range,match(cell_to_match,range_to_match,0))

Comment: =INDEX(Phone!A:B,MATCH(I9,Phone!A:B,0))

Comment: didnt work or may be i have made some mistake. return range was the user input one, cell to march was the number, range was again user inputs ones, and match 0

Comment: Your ranges include two columns i.e phones!A:B make sure you select only one column in your ranges

Comment: my guess is you want `=INDEX(Phone!B:B,MATCH(I9,Phone!A:A,0))` @Joanne