# Alternative to vlookup with index and match in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, vlookup, vba

```
Cell A1: 0553400710 
Cell A2: John
Cell B1: ['0553400710', '0553439406']
```

Note:

1. Cell B1 has a fixed format of ['number','number,'number',...... ]
2. A1 and A2 are user input values
3. I want to match 0553400710 in Cell A1 with ['0553400710', '0553439406'] in Cell B1.

If it matches, I want to return A2: John.

Is it possible?

I have asked the question before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38149171/alternative-to-vlookup-with-exact-and-approximate-match-doesnt-work/38149618?noredirect=1#comment63729236_38149618). it has all the pictures attached as well. Unfortunately no one except one could solve it.

The one who gave me a nearest answer was [Jeeped](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4039065/jeeped) whose answer is

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(A:A, MATCH("*"&A1&"*",B:B, 0)+1), "")
```

The problem with this is that it takes the column array instead of rows array. I need it to be in rows as its the best practice for a database. Is there anyone who can improve this solution?

I have also tried vlookup as below but it failed

[image]

Here is the data for reference 
[image]

and here is the input i am trying to match

[image]

Comment: It takes in two column array but it evaluates one row at a time until it find a match.  I don't see how that is different than a database.  Does the function work?  Are you just trying for better performance?

Comment: You would probably be interested in this article [EXCEL VLOOKUP VS INDEX MATCH VS SQL VS VBA](http://analystcave.com/excel-vlookup-vs-index-match-vs-sql-performance/).  It's benchmarks different lookup methods.  It says the `DOUBLE TRUE VLOOKUP` out performs all other worksheet lookups.

Comment: I want user inputs in 'number' and 'name'  A1 and B1 respectively. I dont like to put number in one cell and their name in the cell below it and have a long column of name number.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible?

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(A1,B1)),A2,"number not found")
```

This will work for your example at the top. If A1 looks like ['0553400710'] you could try using SUBSTITUTE formula to remove punctuation.

Not sure what you were trying to do in the bottom bit, sorry.